# EditText error disappearing with invalid key on numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

I have a simple EditText with a TextWatcher where a validation is performed. In the TextWatcher the error is set correctly and the pop-up and message is appearing has expected.

I am doing a Range validation. The EditText type is set to number and has expected, the keyboard shown is only digit. **But** this keyboard, shows space, comma, minus and dot as well. Since I set the type to be a number, these keys aren't allowed and it's ok. But if an error is set and visible, and the user click on not allowed key, the error pop-up disappear.

I found a solution by allowing the keys like the example below:

```
textEditInputText.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789 -.,")
```

But I was wondering why I have to do that and how the error message could stay when the user click on invalid keys?